# Namespace Issues in Visual Studio Automated Builds

Tags: c#, azure, namespaces, azure-devops, automated-deployment

Having a bit of an issue with automated builds in Visual Studio Team Services (previously VSO, TFS Online).

I have a class that is referencing a namespace that is this format:

Project.Name.Name.Folder

The issue is there is class named:

Project.Name.

There is no issue in Visual Studio when building or even packaging the project for Azure and it deploys manually fine, but when I run automated builds it comes back with and error that basically states that Name does not exist in namespace Project.Name, so it's obviously looking in the wrong project when it runs the automated build.

Is there some syntax I can use to basically notate what is specifically the class name and then the folder path inside the class?

ex: [Project.Name.Name].Folder

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Different builds using different versions of the framework?  Its unlikely but possible.  Also, just fully qualify the class that is giving you issues.  If you must, prefix it with the global scope `global::Project.Name`.  That's kind of a workaround but will get you past this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out VS was just confused :/ 
If I removed the reference, re-added it, and then removed the using statement and re-added it, the issue was resolved. To be fair, the solution built, ran, and even manually deployed to Azure just fine. It was Continuous Integration that was being problematic with it.